# Expected length of unit segments

Tags: expectation

Suppose we draw $x, y, z$ from the uniform distribution on $(0, 5)$. How would we calculate the expected value of $|(x, x + 1) \cup (y, y  + 1) \cup (z, z+1)|$?

Comment: Where are they drawn? In a plane, in the space on a line. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: @Raffaele I am not too sure what you mean. Here $x, y, z$ are randomly generated reals from $U(0,5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477320/expected-overlap) might be of some interest to you. I'll use a similar method to talk about the points covered by at least one segment. Let $p_1(t)$ be the probability that a point $t\in[0, 6]$ is covered by a particular segment. If the segment's start is placed at position $x$, $p_1(t)$ is the ratio of the length of the interval of $x$ values that result in $t$ being covered and the total interval from which $x$ is drawn. From this, we can obtain a piecewise expression for $p_1(t)$:

$$
p_1(t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {t}{5}   & 0 \le t < 1   \newline
\frac {1}{5}   & 1 \le t < 5   \newline
\frac {6-t}{5} & 5 \le t \le 6 \newline
\end{cases}
$$

If we integrate $p_1(t)$ on $[0, 6]$, we obtain the expected size of the interval of points covered, which is of course $1$. To obtain the expected length covered by 3 segments, we need to obtain the probability that a point be covered by at least one of 3 such segments, chosen independently, which I'll call $q(t)$.

To do this, we can note that the probability of not being covered by a particular segment is $1-p_1(t)$ Since the probability of being covered be a particular segment is independent of being covered by another segment, the probability of *not* being covered by *any* of the 3 segments is simply $(1-p_1(t))^3$. Thus, the probability of being covered by at least one segment is the compliment, $q(t) = 1-(1-p_1(t))^3$. We can plug our piecewise expression for $p_1(t)$ into this relation to obtain $q(t)$.

$$
q(t) =
\begin{cases}
1 - (1 - \frac t 5)^3   & 0 \le t < 1  \newline
1 - (1 - \frac  1 5)^3  & 1 \le t < 5   \newline
1 - (1 - \frac{6-t}5)^3 & 5 \le t \le 6 \newline
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{125} t^3 - \frac{3}{25} t^2 + \frac{3}{5} t & 0 \le t < 1   \newline
\frac{61}{125} & 1 \le t < 5   \newline
\frac{1}{125} (6-t)^3 - \frac{3}{25} (6-t)^2 + \frac{3}{5} (6-t) & 5 \le t \le 6 \newline
\end{cases}
$$

To obtain the expected length, all we need to do is evaluate the integral:

$$\int_0^6q(t) dt = \int_0^1q(t) dt + \int_1^5q(t) dt + \int_5^6q(t) dt$$

Notice that the first and last integrals are equivalent due to symmetry. After a bit of calculus, we obtain the expected length of $\frac{619}{250}$.